Android Studio : Fix all 'xxx' problems in file
Intellij has an option to fix multiple identical issues in one go. Look for example at the following simple issue of multiple variables not being final :

Using Fix all 'Local variable or parameter can be 'final'' problems in file I can fix all at once. Is there the same for Android Studio (Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1)?
